# \renewcommand{\cite} does not work

Tags: citing, macros

I'm using `\cite` a lot in my document, but now I discovered that I really need `\citep` instead (from natbib). No problem, I thought, just redefine the `\cite` command:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\citep{#1}}
```

That worked for the `LaTeX` version on my laptop (Mac), but on my Linux box this `\renewcommand` has no effect.

How can I safely redefine the `\cite` command, so that it works on all LaTeX distributions?

P.S.: The version where it didn't work is this:

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
```

Update: After `\let` didn't work either (see answer) I found the source of the trouble: I had the `\usepackage{natbib}` command *after* my `\renewcommand{\cite}` command. Changing the order fixed it.

Comment: The problem is solved, but a general tip for such cases: surround the `\Renewcommand\foo` with `\show\foo`, and put this again at a place where the command is used.  You will see the changes to the macro.

Answer (score 16):

As you noted, the order matters. Note that you can get roughly the same effect of your \renewcommand with less work by doing

```
\renewcommand\cite{\citep}
```

That is, you don't need the argument. This can often be necessary for things like \url that change catcodes before looking at arguments, but probably don't make any difference in this case.

Comment: Not reading the argument oneself will also make life easier if the command in question has a starred form or other fancy variations.

Answer (score 8):

You could try

```
\let\cite\citep
```

instead.

Update: after seeing your upated question: I assume `\let` would have worked if you would have placed it after `\usepackage{natbib}` as well. Generally, placing redefinitions after all packages have been loaded prevents macros from beeing accidentally overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

These problems can be avoided by using \AtBeginDocument, for example:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\cite{\citep}}
```

If you are creating your own packages then this will allow you to load your package before natbib and still redefine the citation command.