# Renew \ref command doesn't work

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm trying renew \ref command to auto detect equation and figure. All my labels of equations start with "eq:" and all labels of figures with "fig:".

So I try this way, but it isn't works for me:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% Is it equation? => add brackets
\newcommand\myref[1]{\in@{eq:}{#1} \ifin@ (\ref{#1}) \else \ref{#1} \fi }
\makeatother

%\let\ref\myref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\myref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\myref{#1}}

\begin{document}
Cite to eq: \cite{eq:test}, cite to fig: \cite{fig:test} % WORK FINE, add brackets
Ref to eq: \ref{eq:test}, ref to fig: \ref{fig:test}     % DOESN'T WORK :-(

\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=13cm]{img/test.png}
 \caption{test}
 \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
 a = b
 \label{eq:test}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The output is, that \cite behave as I want (add brackets, if label starts with "eq"), but \ref doesn't. It is ignoring me:-(

(I inspired in thread [\renewcommand{\cite} does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/renewcommand-cite-does-not-work) ; so I tried command \let too)

I know about \eqref, but I have in many documents \ref and now I want to highlight equations with brackets.

Some idea?

Thanks.

Comment: hyperref's `\autoref` can probably do what you are trying to do with this command...

Answer (score 5):

Something (eg hyperref) is likely redefining `\ref` in the `\AtBeginDocument` hook. You can try moving your definitions out of the preamble. For the kind of thing you are trying to do I would recommend checking into the `cleveref` package, which can do many intelligent things with referencing commands.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that Lev is right. In the document you posted, your `\ref` macro is never called since it is redefined again at `\begin{document}`. If you move your definitions out of the preamble, then you'll get what I expected: `\ref` calls `\myref`, this calls again `\ref`, and you'll get a closed loop that'll produce a "TeX capacity exceeded" error. You indeed have to use `\let` in order to avoid this:

```
\let\oldref\ref
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myref[1]{\in@{eq:}{#1} \ifin@ (\oldref{#1}) \else \oldref{#1} \fi }
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\myref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\myref{#1}}
```

Put this after `\begin{document}`, and everything will be as you wanted. Explanation: `\let` saves the original definition of `\ref` to `\oldref`, and the original definition can then be used in your `\myref`. This can't be done with `\newcommand`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel; instead, use [fncylab](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fncylab.html).

After I wrote this I noticed that you wanted to redefine `\cite` also.  Why?  It does not serve the same function as `\ref` and has its own style already.

Comment: No, I don't want redefine \cite, it was only example that my \myref works fine. Problem solved (see below), thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Great, it works, thanks a lot!

But if I use my \myref with calling \ref, I obtain this error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry.
```

I don't know why, but maybe it makes cycle \ref-->\myref-->\ref-->\myref...

So I use directly this way (cref gives brackets arround the equation automaticaly):

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
.
.
.    
\begin{document} \let\ref\cref
```

And can use \ref for figure, tables, equation and for equation brackets are automaticaly added.

If you want change name of label, simply add to preambule:

```
\crefname{equation}{singular}{plural}
\crefname{figure}{singular}{plural}
```

See [Manual for cleveref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) (PDF)