# Table, Figure, and Listing prefixes

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, lyx

### Background

Using LyX and KOMA Script to author a technical manual.

### Problem

The documents are strewn with the following references:

```
\ref{fig:Example-Database-Type}
```

When converted to PDF, this results in "1.1" for the figure number, whereas I would prefer it to read "Figure 1.1". Similarly, for Tables and Listings, they should read "Table 1.1" and "Listing 1.1", respectively.

### Code

The caption code is:

```
\caption{\label{fig:Example-Query-Statement}Example Query Statement}
```

The reference code is:

```
\ref{fig:Example-Query-Statement}
```

The document preamble includes:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

The result is: "The screen shot in 1.1 shows ..."

The desired result is: "The screen shot in Figure 1.1 shows ..."

### Ideas

Tried:

```
\let\oldref=\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{Figure {\oldref{#1}}}
```

Tried:

```
\usepackage{fancyref}
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\fref{#1}}
```

Tried:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

### Question

How do you change the `\ref` command to include a `\figurename` prefix without having to edit (and thus duplicate) the code for every figure (that already has the `\ref`)?

Thank you!

Comment: see also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5797/how-exactly-does-def-pfigurefigure-work

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/renew-ref-command-doesnt-work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) has `autoref` which takes care of this stuff. It is described briefly [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#The_hyperref_package_and_.5Cautoref.7B.7D).

This solution doesn't do exactly what you want. That is, it doesn't redefine `\ref`. But I'm not sure that's a great idea anyway. (weirdly `\let\ref\autoref` doesn't seem to do anything). So to have what you want, you need to do two things:

Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble and then put `\let\ref\autoref` just *after* your `\begin{document}`

If you don't like the ugly coloured borders hyperref puts on your references [see this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/823/215). Alternatively, you can also add the `nohyperref` package after the hyperref package.

Hyperref causes lots of nasty package conflicts, so put it near the end of your preamble.

Comment: @Dave if you're using hyperref anyway, why use cref, rather than autoref!? It's one less package to load...

Comment: @Dave once you put the `\let\ref\autoref` _after_ the `\begin{document}` it should work fine... And that's the same story with cleveref...