# How to make \ref references include the word 'Figure'?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, babel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table, Figure, and Listing prefixes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/table-figure-and-listing-prefixes)
>   [Automatically inserting “Section, Subsection, etc”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39349/automatically-inserting-section-subsection-etc)

I'm using the package `hyperref`.
When referencing my figure, I currently use code like

```
Figure \ref{fig:chorus-overview} gives an overview of the basic concept.
```

because `\ref` will just yield a single integer `1`, as opposed to `Figure 1`.

However, the word `Figure` is auto-generated for the figure environment caption, so when using a package such as `[ngerman]{babel}`, it's `Abbildung` instead, and I need to fix the text before my reference.

Is there any way to directly get the `Figure 1` text via `\ref` or a similar command?

**EDIT**

Additionally to the steps described in Sveinung's answer (using \autoref from hyperref or \cref from cleveref), I needed to make sure to place the label *before* the caption in the figure environment, as pointed out by Werner, and to include babel *before* hyperref/cleveref.

`\nameref` does not do what I need, since it copies the text of the caption instead.

Comment: Since the question most likely has something to do with the placement of labels, and/or `babel` options, it is probably not an exact duplicate.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the label needs to go before the caption.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Load the package `cleveref` and change your `\ref{label}` to `\cref{label}`. If you prefer to include the label names (chapter, section *etc*.) in the hyperlinks when using
cleveref, you can pass the `nameinlink` option to the cleveref package, see page 10 in the [cleveref-manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/).

As *egreg* emphasizes, the package `cleveref` must be loaded after `hyperref`.

You may instead use `\autoref` from the `hyperref`-package, just change your `\ref{label}` to `\autoref{label}`. See the `hyperref` manual page 15.

If I misunderstood you, and the problem is that you want the English word `Figure` instead of the German word `Abbildung`, you have two possibilities:

1. Either load `babel` with the option `UKenglish` instead of `ngerman` if your text is in English, or
2. if your text is in German, but you still want to use the English word `figure`, you can use the `babel`-environment `\begin{otherlanguage}` before your figure, see the `babel-`manual page 6 (use `texdoc babel` at a command prompt).

Comment: The package `cleveref` must be loaded *after* `hyperref`. Just a reminder, but it's important because usually it's the other way around and people don't read manuals. :)

Comment: @mic_e: This may be because you have your `\label` and `\caption` command inverted. See [Where to put the `\label` on a `figure` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35137/5764)

Comment: I've solved the problem now. I made two mistakes: First, I included hyperref before including babel, and second, I placed \label before \caption. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mic_e Note that, with some exceptions such as `cleveref`, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package. See [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)

Comment: +1. Note that notifications like "@egreg" don't work in answers.

Comment: just a tiny thing, it generates fig. x.y, while i would prefer Fig. x.y; is there any simple way to achieve that?