# Automatic text for labeling lemmas, examples etc

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

If I label an equation I use

```
\label{bla}
\eqref{bla}
```

since then it automaticalls copies the number of the equation e.g. 1.1 and with \eqref{bla} I get (1.1) with the link to the equation - perfect...
However, I defined many other things like "Lemma", "Remark", "Example", Theorem" etc. Now is there something like eqref that automatically checks the title, e.g. Lemma 1.2 and then writes "Lemma 1.2" with the link to it similar to eqref?

Or do I need to define it? If yes- how could I do it?

Comment: Have a look to the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [How to make `\ref` references include the word 'Figure'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62611/5764); [Automatically inserting "Section", "Subsection", etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39349/5764)