# Can you employ \unskip to automatically place a non-breaking space before \cite or \ref?

Tags: macros, spacing, citing

It is recommended to place a non-breaking space before `\cite`, `\ref`, inline math  and perhaps at few other locations.

The question is whether you can design an improved version of `\cite` (say) which would  gobble all the preceding spaces, insert a non-breaking space, and then proceed to calling the original `\cite`?

Comment: @Yossi: Why did you tag your question with `{tex-core}`?

Comment: Oh, because I thought it had to do with the way TeX consumes characters. If it ain't so, I will gladly fix the tagging.

Comment: Well, I tried fixing that, but could not change the tags. Perhaps the high ranking members of this friendly and wise community have more privileges than I do?

Comment: @Yossi: Fixed for you.

Comment: @Yossi: And once you have 500 rep (shouldn't be too long now), you may retag questions yourself.

Comment: @lockstep: I may not reach that level ever, since I plan on using all my rep on bounties...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can. The `varioref` package does this already. Have a look at the source code of it. For example:

> ```
> \@vpageref
>     More parsing. . .
> 596 \def\@vpageref[#1]{\@ifnextchar[%
>     The default for the second optional argument is a space which is prexed by
>     \unskip to get rid of any leading space inserted already.
> 597 {\@@vpageref{#1}}{\@@vpageref{#1}[\unskip\vref@space]}}
> ```

You should be able to define:

```
\def\mycite#1{\unskip~\cite{#1}}
```

or save `\cite` away using `\let`:

```
\let\origcite\cite
\def\cite#1{\unskip~\origcite{#1}}
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks. I did not think this would be as easy, since I thought TeX has consumed the preceding spaces already. I think this would be useful to many. I will surely start using this right away.

Comment: @YossiGil: Well TeX has consumed the space indeed, but stored it as a skip which can be removed using the `\unskip`.

Answer (score 4):

Combining Martin's answer with this [redefinition of `\cite` answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/renewcommand-cite-does-not-work), I was able to use the following in my preamble, without needing the `varioref` package:

```
\let\originalcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\unskip~\originalcite{#1}}
```

A good explanation of what's going on with `\let` and `\renewcommand` was found in the [Make your own style section of a LaTeX tutorial](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/anthony.roberts/LaTeX/ltxfloats.html#yourStyle):

> We interfere with LaTeX using the `\let` command which defines a pointer to the *current* definition of another command; thus
>
> ```
> \let\LaTeXtitle\title
> ```
>
> defines \LaTeXtitle to point to the original LaTeX definition of `\title`. Follow this with
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\title}[1]{\LaTeXtitle{\color{magenta}\textsf{#1}}}
> ```
>
> to define a new version of `\title` that colours it magenta and puts it into a sans serif font. Neat!

Comment: Another way is to say `\robustify\cite\preto\cite{\unskip~}` after having loaded the **etoolbox** package; `\robustify` is needed because `\cite` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Otherwise the more obscure `\expandafter\preto\csname cite \endcsname{\unskip~}` is needed (there's a space between `cite` and `\endcsname`).

Comment: Of course one has to be very careful not to start a sentence with `\cite`, so I prefer always to put a `~` before `\cite` so that I can delete it in troublesome cases; and the `~` is probably wrong when an author-date system is used.

Comment: Done this way: `\let\originalcite\cite` `\def\cite{\unskip~\originalcite}`, it works with the optional argument too, e.g., `\cite[p. 10]{Foo}`. Want to edit your answer?